# Import React Icons- FiMoreHorizontal - Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-icons

Following a tutorial to build a Twitter clone and I have to import:

import { FiMoreHorizontal } from 'react-icons/fi' 2.3K (gzipped: 1K)
import { VscTwitter } from 'react-icons/vsc' 3.1K (gzipped: 1.5K)

I get this.....

Error: error: Identifier cannot follow number

|
1 | import { FiMoreHorizontal } from 'react-icons/fi' 2.3K (gzipped: 1K)
|                                                      ^

Caused by:
0: failed to process js file
1: Syntax Error

Comment: Did you actually install the react icons library in your applications root directory with npm or yarn?  is that `2.3k (gzipped: 1k)` really at the end of your import line?

Comment: Ran this code:   npm install react-icons --save

Comment: import { FiMoreHorizontal } from 'react-icons/fi' 2.3K (gzipped: 1K)
import { VscTwitter } from 'react-icons/vsc' 3.1K (gzipped: 1.5K)
***The next line of code***
const style = {

Comment: @PhilCowan's answer should help. On a side note, to save you a bit of typing, you no longer need the `--save` flag in npm and you can use `i` instead of `install`, so your command can look like this `npm i react-icons`. If installing a dev dependency, run something like this `npm i morgan -D`.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that React Icons was installed in the correct directory, you can double check that by looking in `package.json` if it lists react-icons in the dependencies object you should be good to go.

The import should not include anything after the quotes.

`import { FiMoreHorizontal } from 'react-icons/fi'`